# What do people call aspx files to distinguish them from aspx.cs/aspx.vb code-behind files?

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

In the "code-behind" style of ASP.NET programming, you split your code into two different files, an .aspx file and an aspx.cs file. (That's for C#; for VB, it's aspx.vb instead.) Everyone seems settled on calling the .aspx.cs/.aspx.vb files "code-behind files" or just "code-behinds". The question is: Is there a similarly established term for the .aspx (non-code-behind) files?

I've seen "aspx files", but that is arguably ambiguous.

Stephen Walther uses "presentation pages". ([example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1156955&seqNum=3)) I'm not sure how many other people do.

There might be multiple valid answers here. My main use case, though, is finding the best terminology to use when googling, or when searching or writing things here on Stack Overflow. Sometimes you want to ask or say something about just the "non-code-behind" file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call them "aspx pages" or "aspx files" or even just "aspx-es".

Not sure why you'd think that's arguably ambiguous. Can you elaborate?

Comment: On my team anyway, "aspx page" often means both the codebehind and the designer file. I guess "asp file" is indeed less ambiguous to me than "aspx page". But I still wish Microsoft had a more standardized phrase for "asp file", to enhance the googleability of problems that are specific to it and the declarations/escape sequences that can appear therein.

Answer (score 2):

I usually call it the "@#$%* designer file" or just "designer file."

Comment: Nice. Maybe I'll think about adopting the former for my own personal use.

Answer (score 2):

You can call them **<s>HTML</s> Markup files***.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of code-behind is a separation of back-end logic and front-end presentation. Yes, in the real world, that's not always a clear distinction when all is said and done, but the intent is there.

So I think 'presentation page' makes sense.

I usually just call it the HTML (vs. the .net code in the codebehind)

EDIT: oh, sorry, missed the 'in the context of googling'. I would agree that "aspx page" or "aspx file" would work.

That said, maybe provide us with some example google searches you are doing and we can probably offer suggestions for alternative wording for what you are actually seeking.

Answer (score 0):

When you use C#, VB, whatever code in aspx files, it's called code-inline.

I call aspx files "aspx" or markup file.

Answer (score 0):

In our Project, we just use the terms :

ASPX page / Markup File

and

Code File / Code Behind